# event.target.value handle as ENUM

Tags: reactjs, typescript, enums, material-ui

The event.target.value returns an 'String' value and I would like to have it recognized as an ENUM type.
I have the following code:

```
export enum Permissions {
    OnlyMe,
    Everyone,
    SelectedPerson
}
...

<FormControl>
<InputLabel>Label name</InputLabel>
<NativeSelect
    value={state.user.permission}
    onChange={(event) =>
        setState({
        ...state,
        user: {
            ...state.user,
            permission: event.target.value as Permissions
        }
    })}
>
    <option value={Permissions.OnlyMe}>Only me</option>
    <option value={Permissions.Everyone}>Everyone</option>
    <option value={Permissions.SelectedPerson}>Selected persons</option>
</NativeSelect>
```

I get the typescript error **"Conversion of type 'string' to Permissions may be a mistake because neither type sufficiently overlaps with the other."**

I have already tried:

```
permission: Permissions(event.target.value) or

permission: Permissions(String(event.target.value))
```

but nothing is working.
Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

TypeScript will handle the enum as Number such as:

- 0 for OnlyMe
- 1 for EveryOne
- 2 for SelectedPerson

`event.target.value` will return a string, so your problem is that you are trying to cast string to an integer you can simply do `+event.target.value` that will solve your compilation error by casting the string value using the js hack `+`.

**Note**: the solution above will return a number, in case you wish to get it as string you can do `Permissions[+event.target.value]`

Comment: permission: +event.target.value as Permissions is working and I understand now why, but Permissons[+event.target.value] isn`t working. Typescript still says string not applicable to permission. Anyway it is working with the first one :-) thx

Comment: you can see its working for me here https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-typescript-playground-vd0in it may be a typescript version issue